# How to check data post from input box is URL or not Using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to check if the data input from input box is url or not using PHP in Codeigniter.
How to check data?

For example:

```
$data= "test";
```

I want to check if that data is url or not using php?

Comment: You have a really low accpet rate (33%), try accepting some answers for you old questions please.

Comment: I solved my problem by using parse_url() function. and check if ['scheme']=='http' || ['scheme'] ='https') .

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if(!filter_var($data, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
  echo "Not URL";
}
```

OR:

```
function isValidURL($url)
{
    return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
if(!isValidURL($data)){
    echo 'URL invalide.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

> On seriously malformed URLs, parse_url() may return FALSE.

This is in both PHP 4 (hopefully not your version) and PHP 5.

If you have PHP 5.2 or greater, use [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using parse_url() function. and check if ['scheme']=='http' || ['scheme'] ='https') .